# using anonymous function within scale_y_continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2, anonymous-function

I can call an anonymous function in scale_y_continuous() using `function(y) comma(y)`, but I cannot call an anonymous function using the ~ convention. Is it possible to use ~ in this situation?

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$model <- rownames(mtcars)

# Success
ggplot(mtcars[1:3,], aes(x = model, y = wt*2000)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(y) comma(y))

# Fail
ggplot(mtcars[1:3,], aes(x = model, y = wt*2000)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = ~comma(y))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option is to wrap within `purrr::as_mapper`

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
ggplot(mtcars[1:3,], aes(x = model, y = wt*2000)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = as_mapper(~ comma(.)))
```

Or use `rlang::as_function(~ comma(.))`

---

Or simply use `comma` without any anonymous function call

```
ggplot(mtcars[1:3,], aes(x = model, y = wt*2000)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```

[image]