# R - specifying ggplot2 breaks as a function of the data using ~

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a follow up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60788041/ggplot2-setting-breaks-regardless-of-the-range-of-y-axis/60788336?noredirect=1#comment107556922_60788336) where I asked how to dynamically set the breaks on the y-axis if the dataset I am using is continually updating and therefore, the range of the y-axis is changing.

The answer was to specify the breaks as the function of the data like this:

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks = function(z) seq(0, range(z)[2], by = 10))
```

However, I would like to use the `~` operator which stands in place of anonymous function.

I tried the following two variants, but they didn't work:

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks = ~seq(0, range(z)[2], by = 10))
```

and

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks = ~seq(0, range()[2], by = 10))
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using anonymous function within scale\_y\_continuous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59432347/using-anonymous-function-within-scale-y-continuous)

Comment: you need to call purrr, otherwise the tilda will not make sense, see the link provided above

Answer (score 0):

Try using max(z) instead of range(z)[2]